# Drawing 3d-graphics in WPF or winforms

Tags: .net, wpf, winforms, 3d

I need to display and manipulate data in 3D in winforms or WPF application. It may look something like this:
[image]

What libraries I can use to achieve this goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have a look at [this link](http://kindohm.com/technical/WPF3DTutorial.htm) which is a nice tutorial about the **System.Windows.Media.Media3D** library, which is used in WPF.

Here are some useful links:

[MSDN: System.Windows.Media.Media3D-Namespace](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.media.media3d.aspx)

[3D Game Development with XNA Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/gg266472)

Answer (score 1):

This came up as an answer to what I was looking for. However, I ended up using OpenTK -- an OpenGL control/wrapper for .NET version 2.0 and up (as well as Mono).
http://www.opentk.com/doc/chapter/2/glcontrol